# Using Facebook SDK to send a private message

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I have successfully integrated Facebook login with my app. Now I want to make a button that once pressed will send a private message to another facebook user of my specification. Most information I found online hasn't been helpful because it is very outdated. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can not send a message via API – you can only use the dialog/button Facebook provides for this to let users send a message themselves.

Comment: Hello, Did you find a way to achieve what you wanted to do ?

If you have any documentation or links to provides that would be great. I'm also looking for information right now but didn't find anything yet.

Thanks.